# Error in calc_nv[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, function

I have coded a function for networth -

```
calc_nv <- function(a = d4$Total ,b = dl$`Reserve and Surplus`,
                    c = dl$`Satuatory Reserves`, d = dl$`Satuatory Reserves`,
                    e = dl$`Capital Reserves` ,f = dl$Deposits ,
                    g = dl$Borrowings ,h = dl$`Other Liabilities and Provisions`){
  nv <- a - (b + c + d + e + f + g + h)
  print(nv)
}
```

When I use the function by running the code calc_nv[1] I get Error in calc_nv[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

If I change the brackets from [] to (). For Eg - calc_nv(1). I get Error in b + c : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Can't understand both the errors. Kindly help.

Comment: You call a function with normal parentheses and not with square brackets. The second error means that one of the columns in your data.frame is not numeric. There are more issues with your code, but I leave those to you as a learning experience.

Comment: Hi, Thank You! I have tried to call the function with parenthesis. So how should I change my non-numeric to numeric? Kindly also let me know what are the issues with my code?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (you have  data sets, `d4` and `dl`).

Comment: I have imported the data from excel. What does dput(df) mean?